# SciPy Optimization using SLSQP gives solution that does not satisfy constraints

Tags: python, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to minimize the function
 `B1=0.00299540627439527*x[0]**2 + 0.00701825276534463*x[0]*x[1] + 0.0672877782113971*x[0] + 0.00456646480250456*x[1]**2 + 0.054080834634827*x[1] + 0.298938755491431`
over the state space of `x1=[-10,10]` and `x2=[-10,10]`
given the following inequality constriant 
`EqX0=[[(x[0]+5)**2+x[1]**2-2.5]]<=0`  where `x[0]` and `x[1]` have been symbolically defined as `x1` and `x2`

`ga=1` is a parameter

However, when I use SLSQP to solve the non linear constrained optimization problem, answer leads to x=[-10,10] which does not satisfy the inequality constraint.

Here is the piece of code:

```
def Objective2(ax):
    B2=B1.copy()
    B2=B2.subs((x[i],ax[i]) for i in range(len(ax)))
    return ga-B2

def Constraint1(ax):
    EqX0c=EqX0.copy()
    cc=[]
    for pp in range(len(EqX0c)):
        cc.append(-EqX0c[0][pp].subs((x[i],ax[i]) for i in range(len(ax))))
    return cc

con1= {'type': 'ineq','fun': Constraint1}
bounds=Bounds([-10,10],[-10,10])
sol2=minimize(Objective2,x0,method="SLSQP",bounds=bounds,constraints=con1)
```

This is the output produced. Program terminates successfully but gives the wrong results.

`fun: -0.12123115088124994
     jac: array([-0.07756218, -0.0752276 ])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 4
     nit: 5
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([-10.,  10.])`

Any idea why this is happening and how I can tackle it?

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cannot reproduce, I got numerically admissible value `x = [-3.70887367,  0.91268439]`. Try to replace all sympy subs with normal arithmetic. It will help to localize the problem.

Comment: But the solution `[-10, 10]` is indeed within the bounds you specified.

Comment: @Stelios But the solution does not satisfy the constraints mentioned by the constraint function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrongly defined Bounds. Try `Bounds([-10,-10],[10,10])`.

See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.Bounds.html#scipy.optimize.Bounds).

Comment: In this case I think the link provides context. Looks okay to me